# dynamic view page content JSF

Tags: jsf, friendly-url

i am now using JSF to develop for EJB3, it was read tip how to change URL friendly in JSF
http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/11/friendly-urls-in-jsf.html
but i wonder how can i get parameter for my page

for example if i use JSP 
i have code sample

```
if(("page").equals(request.getparameter("id"))
{
       <jsp:include page="//sameple"// />
}
else if(("page").equals(request.getparameter("user"))
{
       <jsp:include page="//samepl"// />
}
```

with code sample i can get parameter for url : http://localhost:8080/index.jsp?page=id
but in JSF or friendly URL how can i get parameter with URL http://localhost:8080/index.jsp/page/id

Comment: Do you use JSF 2.0? I'm not sure if I understand your question well, do you want to have urls like http://localhost:8080/index.jsp?page=id ?

Comment: yes i used JSF 2.0, i want display friendly url localhost:8080/index/page/id <=== i can do that but i dont know how get parameter example if i use JSP 2.1 with url localhost:8080/index.jsp?page=id  i can get parameter of page is id, but when i using friendly url such as localhost:8080/index.jsp/page/id <<===== how can i get parameter of page???my purpose is switch dynamic sub view example page/id <== show id , page/name <== show name. Do you understand my question?

Comment: That was an old article :) It was at least the inspiration of the author of PrettyFaces. I'd say, go ahead with PrettyFaces.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the pretty faces project (http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/).  It provides URL rewriting for JSF and servlet.  You can make the URLs as "pretty" as you like, and map your parameters into the query string format expected by the JSF 2 viewParams, or inject them into your managed beans directly.

It is an incredibly flexible solution to say the least.